# Do not trigger cell value change event in DataGridView when the value is changed programatically

Tags: c#, .net, events, datagridview

I want to know if there is way to not trigger CellValueChanged event in DataGridView when the value is changed programatically?
I only want to process that event when the user changes the value manually, like by clicking or typing in one of the boxes. In my application I also set the value programatically and do not want to process that event.

Thanks,
Ritesh

Answer (score 1):

Add a conditional to your handler that evaluates whether or not the handler should be used.  Set the value to true when you are changing your CellValue programatically.

```
//set this to true when you want to skip handler
private bool _skipHandler = false;

void Handler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   if (skipHandler)
   {
       skipHandler = false;
       return;
   }
   else
   {
       //handle accordingly
   }
}
```