# How do I trigger the cell value change event in a DataGridView only when done manually?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, events, datagridview

So I know this question was answered ([Do not trigger cell value change event in DataGridView when the value is changed programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239592/do-not-trigger-cell-value-change-event-in-datagridview-when-the-value-is-changed)) but the answer provided wasn't documented enough and it didn't work.

Essentially I'm working in a Cell Value Changed Event of a datagridview by validating the data introduced, if the data is out of a specified range I change it to fit. And there lies the problem; when I do so programmatically it triggers the event twice; which I do not want it to do.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could disable the CellValueChangedEvent when you need to change the value programmatically. After you've changed the value, just re-enable the CellValueChangedEvent eg.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //check whether the value is valid
    var specifiedMax = 100;
    var compareValue = int.Parse(this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
    if (compareValue > specifiedMax)
    {
        //disable the cellvaluechanged event before changing the value
        this.dataGridView1.CellValueChanged -= this.dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;
        try
        {
          this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = 100;
        }
        finally
        {
            //enable the cellvaluechanged event again
            this.dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += this.dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;
        }
    }
}
```